# counting number of pixels smaller than a certain value with GPU

Tags: c++, image, directx, gpu

Suppose that you have a 2D GPU texture resource. What's the best way to count the number of texels that are smaller than a certain value using the GPU (using DirectX, either with or without shader)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but on my screen, all pixels are of the same size. Maybe just because my computer is an Apple product?

Comment: I mean the pixel RGB value

Answer (score 1):

You could count this with two shaders.

1. Replace all rgb-values with 1 or 0, depending on how the value exceeds the treshold or not.
2. Reduce the size of the texture step by step with a filter-kernel, which sum up the texels.
   Let's suppose your texture is 64x64 sized. First you reduce it to 32x32 and sum up the 4 related texels of the inputtexture. Repeat until you're having a 4x4 or 8x8 texture and lock it on CPU-side and sum the rest. The result is your desired texelcount. You could use a bigger kernel like 4x4 to reduce the drawcalls and move more work to the shaders.